# How do I map a port on a container to the host?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, json-server

I'm trying to run a container described by the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.4.0

RUN npm install -g sh
RUN npm install -g json-server

WORKDIR /data
VOLUME /data
COPY db.json /data

CMD json-server --watch db.json --port 3001
```

and specifying the listening port by running:

```
 docker run -it -p 3001:3001 abelalejandro/json-server:final
```

The container seems to be running fine and json-server is telling me it is serving my requests on port 3001 yet I can't get any joy when browsing http://localhost:3001

[image]

Am I missing something on publishing/exposing ports?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is binding to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` (any host).

You can change that by setting:

```
CMD json-server --watch db.json --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3001
```

I'm assuming you are using https://github.com/typicode/json-server.

Comment: As a matter of good practice I would suggest adding EXPOSE instruction into your Dockerfile which would serve as a good documentation for the user running the container. Try building the image with/without EXPOSE instruction and do a docker image inspect abelalejandro/json-server:final to see more metadata attached to the image.